# Postgresql return ERROR: operator does not exist: text ->> unknown when concat two data objects?

Tags: postgresql

I am not able to concat two json objects like the following code:

```
select 

    encode(digest(t->>'class' || t->>'title', 'sha1'),'hex')
    from public."ObjectSource" r, unnest(r.data::jsonb[]) as t
```

please advice
/thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "*concat two json objects*"? What is the value of `t`, and what do you want to do with it?

Comment: Sample data for `"ObjectSource".r` please?

Comment: Looks like an [operator precedence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE) issue, it is evaluated as `((t->>'class') || t)->>'title'`. Judging from your whitespace usage, you meant `(t->>'class') || (t->>'title')`?

Comment: Instead of casting `r.data` to `jsonb[]` and using `unnest`, you most likely want to use `jsonb_array_elements`